# Using WCF with visual studio

Tags: webserver

I cannot install WCF starter kit preview with the Visual Studio Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
AND .net Frame Work 4.5.50709. I cannot see the service pack by default. What can be done with regard to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the WCF Rest Starter Kit is intended for Visual Studio 2008. You are using Visual Studio 2012. They are probably not compatible, or even required to consume WCF services with VS2012. 
You do need VS2012 for the Web to use WCF.